# How does $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ look like?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know $B^I$ is the set of functions $f: I \to B$. In particular:

$\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of sequences with terms from $\mathbb{N}$

$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of sequences with terms from $\mathbb{R}$

$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (functions with one variable that take $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as arguments and map to $\mathbb{R}$)

It seems that ${(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}})^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of sequences with terms from ${\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ (ordered pairs of natural numbers).

How would $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\N{\mathbf N}$By the very definition $\N^{\N\times \N}$ is the (not *a*) set of maps $\N \times \N \to \N$. You can imagine a member $a \in \N^{\N \times \N}$ for example as an infinite matrix $(a_{m,n})_{m,n\in \N}$ with entries from $\N$.

Answer (score 3):

That would be the set of maps from ${\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Each element of this set maps ordered pairs of natural numbers to a natural number; for example:
$$f : {\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{N} : (m,n) \mapsto m+n$$
You could visualize this map as:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&1& 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots\\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5& \cdots\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6& \cdots\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7& \cdots\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8& \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}$$